# Get Account Data and export to xml

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory, append, export-to-xml

I need to export some attributes from active directory user accounts to xml containg Displayname, email, officephone, mobile, office and department. I got this powershell code

```
foreach ($User in (get-AdUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Path,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Property *)){
    $DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
    $OfficePhone = $User.OfficePhone
    $MobilePhone = $User.MobilePhone
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Department = $User.Department

    $Prop=[ordered]@{
        "DisplayName" = $DisplayName
        'EmailAddress' = $EmailAddress
        'OfficePhone' = $OfficePhone
        'MobilePhone' = $MobilePhone
        'Office' = $Office
        'Department' = $Department
    }
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop

    $xml += $obj | Export-Clixml W:\skripts\OutFile.xml
}
```

But the result in the xml file only contain one user, the last one. I cant figure out where i do wrong.

Regards
Niklas
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your original script is that you have your Export-Clixml inside your foreach loop.  Beyond that, you shouldn't be doing this:

```
$xml += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop
```

If you want those objects stored in an array to use later, this is much faster:

```
$xml = 
foreach ($User in (get-AdUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Path,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Property *)){
    $DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
    $OfficePhone = $User.OfficePhone
    $MobilePhone = $User.MobilePhone
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Department = $User.Department

    $Prop=[ordered]@{
        "DisplayName" = $DisplayName
        'EmailAddress' = $EmailAddress
        'OfficePhone' = $OfficePhone
        'MobilePhone' = $MobilePhone
        'Office' = $Office
        'Department' = $Department
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop
}

$xml | Export-Clixml W:\skripts\OutFile.xml
```

If all you need is the export file, you don't really need the $xml variable at all. Just wrap the whole foreach loop in a sub-expression and pipe that directly to your export cmdlet:

```
$(foreach ($User in (get-AdUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Path,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Property *)){
    $DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
    $OfficePhone = $User.OfficePhone
    $MobilePhone = $User.MobilePhone
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Department = $User.Department

    $Prop=[ordered]@{
        "DisplayName" = $DisplayName
        'EmailAddress' = $EmailAddress
        'OfficePhone' = $OfficePhone
        'MobilePhone' = $MobilePhone
        'Office' = $Office
        'Department' = $Department
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop
}) | Export-Clixml W:\skripts\OutFile.xml
```

And if you're not changing any of the property names, the whole thing could be replaced with this:

```
$props = 'DisplayName','EmailAddress','OfficePhone','MobilePhone','Office','Department'

get-AdUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Path,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Property $props |
 select $props | Export-Clixml W:\skripts\OutFile.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, the script works fine and I also have learned something new. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the results within for for loop, this should do it:

```
foreach ($User in (get-AdUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Path,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Property *)){
    $DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
    $OfficePhone = $User.OfficePhone
    $MobilePhone = $User.MobilePhone
    $Office = $User.Office
    $Department = $User.Department

    $Prop=[ordered]@{
        "DisplayName" = $DisplayName
        'EmailAddress' = $EmailAddress
        'OfficePhone' = $OfficePhone
        'MobilePhone' = $MobilePhone
        'Office' = $Office
        'Department' = $Department
    }
    $xml += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop
}

$xml | Export-Clixml W:\skripts\OutFile.xml
```